# Template event not firing in Meteor

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

First of all, word of explanation: I'm new to all this Meteor stuff so it might be a stupid question. In my Meteor code I have a template:

```
<template name="hour_form">
  <form id="add_hours">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" id="add_hours_description" placeholder="Input hours">
      <input type="submit" id="add_hours_submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</template>
```

and matching Coffeescript:

```
Template.hour_form.events =
  'submit form': (event) ->
    console.log "Form::submit fired!"
```

Unfortunately for some reason, the event doesn't work. Any ideas why it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this (nearly) working. Seems it was a missing `event.preventDefault()`. I get another error now but that's a different story.